# Is there an 'on button disabled' event?

Tags: jquery, html, button

Or how would I emulate it? What's going on is that I a bunch of buttons, many of which are disabled upon load, then has that attribute toggled depending on specific conditions. What I want to do is to give an option that allows disabled buttons to be hidden. If this is true, as soon as a button is disabled, I want it to be hidden--and when it's enabled afterwards, I want it to be visible. How would I do this?

Right now I have a button that just does this on click:

```
$("button:disabled").toggle();
```

I'm thinking that I can have a function that disables/enables buttons, and in there check if a `shouldHideDisabledButtons` flag or so is on, and if so, hide or show it. This seems like too much though, so I'm looking to see if there's a better way.

Comment: There's no such event, just hide and show the button instead of disabling it ?

Comment: What have you tried? What are you familiar with? You could do this in any number of ways, including CSS and Javascript, but you need to show us some examples of what you've done, so far.

Comment: @adeno I would like to give the option that they could be hidden.

Comment: @mori57 Edited the post. Both CSS and Javscript would be fine.

Comment: `button[disabled] { visibility:hidden }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add class to body based on if user selected to show or hide buttons

http://jsfiddle.net/3hHrD/

CSS

```
.hide button[disabled] {
    display: none;
}
```

JS

```
$(function(){
function toggle() {
    $(document.body).removeClass("show hide").addClass($("#showHide").val());   
}
$("#showHide").change(toggle);

toggle();
});
```

HTML

```
<select id="showHide">
    <option value="show" selected="selected">Show</option>
    <option value="hide">Hide</option>    
</select>
<button disabled>Disabled</button>
<button>Enabled</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing this: `$("#mainButtons button").toggleClass("hiddenDisabled");` with css `button[disabled].hiddenDisabled {
 display: none;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to handle this for you and call it whenever you want to change the property. For example:

**HTML Markup:**

```
<button type="button" id="my-button">Go</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var shouldHideButtonsFlag = true;

    function buttonState($button, disabled) {
        $button.prop('disabled', disabled);
        (disabled && shouldHideButtonsFlag) ? $button.hide() : $button.show();
    }

    buttonState($('#my-button'), true);    // Disables and hides button
    buttonState($('#my-button'), false);   // Enables and shows button
</script>
```

**Edit:**

- Added flag to show or hide button based on user choice per updated request.